# Where does the stress mark go in Межибовский?

Tags: ударение

I've recently figured out how my last name is spelled in russian. When my ancestors came to Argentina (and transliterated their last name) they wrote Mellibovsky ("ll" is a phoneme that in rioplatense spanish is quite similar to ж) and after two generations someone substracted the "v". That kind of stuff make it harder for me to find the equivalent in russian. Now that I've found it, does anybody knows where does the stress mark go in Межибовский?

Comment: Your last name is most probably of Polish origin (Międzyborski). Most Polish words are stressed on the penultimate (next to last) syllable: Międzyb**o**rski.

Comment: Actually most Polish words are stressed on the second syllable.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea. I saw some ukranian and russian people with the last name Межибовский so I thought it was slavic.

Comment: user5937: Polish is Slavic too.

Comment: @VictorBazarov: second from the end

Answer (score 1):

This name is certainly of Polish origin. Also, there is a town in Ukraine, Khmelnitsky region - [Меджибож](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B6) (ukr. Меджибіж).

*Меджи́бож* is stressed on the second syllable, but name *Межибо́вский* should have stress on the 3rd syllable.

Answer (score 0):

The family names which end by -овский have Polish origin.  In Polish, the stress is almost always on the next-to-last syllable (it is called penultimate stress).  Therefore, the stress in family names which end by -овский is on -о (...о́вский)